# Read first half of file contents and echo and then the second half

Tags: php

I have a text file that lists the name of a track then after a double space the artist is listed. In order for me to fetch the album art from Last.fm I have to have both the title and artist in the the URL like `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&track=TRACK TITLE&artist=ARTIST`. Since the artist and track title aren't in separate files, is there a way I can get the part before the double space and call it $title and the part after the double space and call it $artist, so I can just echo it into the URL?

This is what I currently have to get the file contents:

```
<?php
$current = file_get_contents('RBDS%20Text.txt');
echo $current;
?>
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

So the text file outputs the "track title [double space] artist"

For Last.FM I have to have in the URL `track=TRACK TITLE&artist=ARTIST`

Comment: you read the whole file then process that.

Comment: Can you add to your question a couple of lines of input, and the output you need it to generate?  Also, aside from just getting the data, what have you tried in terms of converting it to the format you need?

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'll accept an answer as soon as it lets me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, you want something like this:

```
list($title, $track) = explode('  ', trim(file_get_contents('RBDS%20Text.txt')), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode`.

```
$current = file_get_contents("RBDS%20Text.txt");
$chunks = explode("  ", $current, 2);
$title = $chunks[0];
$artist = $chunks[1];
```

The only issue with the above is that if the title contains a double space, it can potentially encounter issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// build $url here
$result = file_get_contents($url);
list($title, $artist) = explode("  ", $result);
```

You can now access your vars through `$title` and `$artist`

Answer (score 0):

First off, our data...

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat RBDS_Text.txt 
My first song  Crazy Bad Band
Thriller  Michael Jackson
```

Next, a PHP script:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat rbds.php 
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

$lines = file("RBDS_Text.txt");

$fmt="http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&track=%s&artist=%s";

foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $data=explode("  ",$line);
        printf($fmt, urlencode($data[0]), urlencode($data[1]));
        print "\n";
}
```

And finally, the script in action:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./rbds.php 
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&track=My+first+song&artist=Crazy+Bad+Band%0A
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&track=Thriller&artist=Michael+Jackson%0A
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

If you want to use these URLs for something, you can assign them to a variable by replacing the `printf()` line with a [`$varname=sprintf(...)`](http://php.net/sprintf).

Comment: I should learn not to waste 5 minutes on an answer when a two-liner will do.  <sigh>